# Input - Only numbers on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, mobile, input

I want a input field where you only can type numbers (no comma, dots, hashtags,...). I have this code in javascript:

```
function nummer(evt)
{
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And the HTML

```
<input name="pers" type="tel" required="required" id="pers" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return nummer(event)" size="2" maxlength="2" />
```

On a desktop browser, this works perfect, but on a mobile browser you can still type a comma, hashtag,...

Someone an idea what the problem is?

Comment: how about input type="number"?

Comment: Does the mobile browser support javascript fully...

Comment: @StijnBernards Same issue.

Comment: @Rakshit Yes, it is tested on the latest version of chrome for android and windows phone (standard browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this attribute to the `pattern="\d+"` to the input tag which accepts only numbers as input

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using pattern attribute of HTML 5. For your case it will be something like this `pattern="{0-9}"`. In this user will be able to enter alphabets and symbols also but the form will not submit untill the user enters numbers only.

Comment: Great, this does the trick. Is there a way to change the standard message if it is not filled in correctly?

Comment: You can first assign it by using `title="Your Message"` and then if you want to change this later on the you will have to assign an id to the input tag and then in javascript use this `document.getElementById("your_id").title="Changed Message";`.